# How to get rid of dropdown color hamburger menu (and if possible, loading delay) on responsive site?

Tags: responsive-design, joomla, responsive, hamburger-menu

I have a question.
I have a personal Joomla 3.10.11 site, PHP version 8which has a strange phenomenon when showing up in responsive mode (see picture). The hamburger menu drops down in green, and then dissapears again.

[a picture of what happens](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qSgxv.png)

If I go to pagespeed, https://pagespeed.web.dev/report?url=https%3A%2F%2Fmarliesschijven.nl%2F I see this.
Now I am not a developer, but can work via ftp in my site on my .css and other files. How do I solve this?

Can't seem to figure this one out